# Change play's class path to have my logging jar ahead

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, slf4j, logback

I am using Play framework 2.1 which uses logback.
However, I have my own native library which can bind to slf4j.
Since slf4j can bind to single binding which appears higher in the class path,
it is picking up logback rather than mine which is lower in the class path.

How can I configure play class path so that my library is higher in the class path than logback?